# Set Default value of ImageField in Page layout

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout

I have a page layout with a field defined like so:

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField FieldName="30809220-9D7B-4124-8672-4DBBCEA8C67D" runat="server"></PublishingWebControls:RichImageField>
```

Everything is working fine with it. 
My question is, how can I set its default value in Element.xml?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1289663/sharepoint-richimagefield-set-default-image in the question he already mention the anwser

Answer (score 0):

`RichImageField` has a `Value` property. You can leverage that for setting the default image

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField FieldName="30809220-9D7B-4124-8672-4DBBCEA8C67D" runat="server" Value="ImagePath" />
```

Comment: Will that work, according to link mentioned by Waqar this doesn't work! have you tested it?